# how can i give colours to the specific date in calendar in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to give colours to the specific date in my calendar. for example Sunday is holiday so it should be red and if there are any holidays in the weeks i need to give colour to them. how can it be done?

```
var React = require('react');
var DatePicker = require('react-datepicker');
var moment = require('moment');

require('react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css');

class Calender extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment()
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(date) {

    this.setState({ startDate: date });
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <div className="cal">
        <DatePicker className="datepic"
          inline
          fixedHeight
          fixedWidth
          selected={this.state.startDate}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          showYearDropdown
          monthsShown={2} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Calender;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a section on highlighting dates here:

[DatePicker Doc](https://hacker0x01.github.io/react-datepicker/#example-9)

Using the highlighted option adds a class of "react-datepicker__day--highlighted" to the div of the particular day(s) you choose. You can overwrite that style in your css to specify a different background color, text color, etc...